# Naming conventions for numbered variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, naming-conventions, eslint, prettier

I'm new to JS and I'm not sure if this is something that you actually run in to in real-world scenarios. So please forgive me if this question turns out to be trivial.

We're currently learning about test-driven dev and when we create different edge cases to test for our code, I find myself having trouble deciding how to number the variables. For example:

```js
const actual1 = foo(bar);
const expected_1 = 'foo bar';
const testNameSixtyNine = 'should foo when foo bars';

const actualFourTwenty = foo(bar);
const expected_twenty_nine = 'why?'
const testNameDavieFiveZeroFour = 'slap bass';
// etc.
```

Which way is *most* standard? Which is most common? What do you tend to see in high quality code vs poor quality code?

I just want to be loved and to appease the OCD overlords in my brain.

I've searched stackoverflow, styleguides, I've asked around, and there doesn't seem to be much literature on the topic. So I'm hoping someone with real-world experience can chime in and offer some insight how numbering variables is addressed in actual code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be writing *different tests*, rather than having different `expected` and `actual` variables. One unit test should ideally test exactly one thing and should have a single reason to fail or pass. On the occasions where you might need more than one check, you can most likely leverage the testing library's assertions, e.g., `expect(result).to.not.be(1); expect(result).to.be.positive();`. You're still testing a single result but have two conditions to pass. Again, ideally, you'd have only one to make it absolutely clear what is failing and why. I'd be tempted to write two test for this.

Comment: ok seems reasonable. Thanks for the insight. How about the numbering bit in other situations? Do you find yourself using numbered variables often, if ever?

Comment: It's almost never, to be honest. There are a few exceptions but overall it's not common at all. Sometimes you need to take two variables that represent the same type of data but you don't really need to distinguish them via a label, e.g., when sorting and you take two items. Usually then I'd call them `a` and `b` or `x` and `y` - just ascending letters. If working with geometric shapes or similar, I might do `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`. for the X/Y coordinates of two different points. But that's mostly it when it comes to numbered variables - if there are more than two, I'd usually go for array.